# Start Charging clients?

Tags: theater, sound-effects, sound-design, theatre-sound-design

Hey all! I have been working with a theater here in Arizona, I started there as an intern for credit, and now that my hours are done, I think its time to start charging them for the time I work for them. I'm not sure how to bring it up with the owners and how to start asking for money. It costs me a lot to get there, its about an hour drive to get there for the shows and rehearsals. So for 1 full week, and 2 to 3 weekends I am spending everyday 2 hours driving, plus about 4 to 6 hours there for only about 30 min of work, since I am only doing the board op while there. I do all the sound designing for the shows at home, and work about 40 hours total the month before designing the show sound effects, scene change riffs, and also doing the preshow announcement recording and editing. I think I rambled about this, but I hope I got all the info needed for some help. If not I can edit or add in, thanks all!

Answer (score 2):

Hey there, by the sounds of it you should be getting a full wage! I think you should definitely mention how much you're working and how much you're driving to your employer and ask for a wage.

Only thing is, for some unknown reason, people can be funny around money (especially when it's for sound!). So you'll have to think of a tactful way to approach it. But for the amount of work you're doing, continually, you definitely deserve to be paid. Or I imagine you won't be able to keep it up for them.

Best of luck with it,
Nicol

Comment: ya, they know how much I drive to get there, they were giving me a gas allowance during my internship because I was told they would do "anything" to get me down there, cause I am apparently the "best" *only* sound person they have actually had. I don't think they know how much work I am actually putting into the design of it all. 

Answer (score 0):

There's no tactful way to bring it up.  Be a straight shoot and just ask to speak with the person (who writes the checks) after a rehearsal. Tell them you need to start paying some bills like the rest of the world and your hourly rate is xx per hour and do they prefer invoicing or a weekly time card.  Then shut up.

Don't say anything till they finish there rebuttal. If they really value your work, they'll easily pay your rate and it'll be a done matter.

If not, then explain to them the hours and type of work you put into their business, just like electricity, it's a bill, not an option not to have sound.